# Link in foreign keys in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, phpmyadmin

I have foreign keys set in a mysql db. I have backed up my db from one server to a new one. Both the new and the old server use phpmyadmin. On the old server, y used to have a link in the view of a table from the foreign key to the respective register in the other table. An html link that leads me to the register in the other table. But it doesn't appear on the new server.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set up the pmadb meta-tables: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#linked-tables

After that, you should get the links between foreign keys when browsing. You can also use $cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] to set up the relations you want hyperlinked by hand: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#cfg_Servers_relation

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you mean. In order to import data to a new phpMyAdmin, you need to export the data to sql and import the exported sql file. All the foreign key will still remain the same as what you have imported is in the form of sql.